# Python function-unexpected output

Tags: python, function, output

I have this Python function:

```
def main(n,x):
   g=0
   for i in range(1,n):
       g+=((-1)^i)*(x^(2*i+1))/(2*i+1)
   return g

print main(3,2)
```

and the output is -6, when I think it should be 86/15. Where is my mistake? I want to find the n-value of x-(x^3)/3+(x^5)/5+...

Comment: @VasilisG. Why? Default step is `1`.

Comment: `range(1,n,2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues with your current solution:

1. Your exponentiation operator should be `**` not `^` which is XOR.
2. You should start `range` from 0 not 1 (then first multiplier is `-1**0 = 1`)
3. Change one of the numbers in the division to float, to avoid integer division in Python 2.

---

```
def main(n, x):
   g = 0
   for i in range(n):
       g += ((-1)**i) * (x**(2*i+1))/float(2*i+1)
   return g
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to solve this problem without the use of "for" or "while"?

Comment: @M.Papapetros My (power) series maths is a bit rusty. Try asking on https://math.stackexchange.com/ if there's an arithmetic reduction for your series.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your answer in fraction you can use:

```
from fractions import Fraction
def main(n,x):
   g=0
   for i in range(n):
       g+=Fraction(((-1)**i)*(x**(2*i+1)),(2*i+1))
   return g

print main(3,2)
```

It gives output:

`86/15`